# How to open Image modal on Image click

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I have been working on a code to tag images. First I display a set of images in the screen, which on click should open a modal.

I have tried the following code:

```
  <div id="gallery ">

   <?php
     foreach ($gallery as $i) {
    ?>
    <img href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" src="<?php echo "$i"; ?>" class="modal_img">

   <?php }
    ?>
   </div>
```

The above code is used to display a set of images from an array. The following code I tried to create a Modal:

```
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
   <input type="hidden" id="result"></input>

   <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <div id="imagearea" class="imagearea">

  <span class="right_sec_text">Draw a Box over what captured your attention</span>

  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  </div>
   <div class="footer_btn">
    <p><button class="btn_success" id="btn_add" value="add areas">Confirm</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**Image**: shows the screen with image
[image]

So when the image is clicked the modal should open . I tried the following code to open the modal, but its not responding. I tried to get the imagename in console log, and it works. but the modal doesnt open.

```
  $(function(){
     $(".modal_img").on("click",function(){
     var src = $(this).attr("src");
     $("#img01").prop("src",src);
     console.log(src);
    })
   })
```

CSS:

```
 #myModal {
 display: none; /* Hidden by default */
 position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
 z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
 padding-top: 20px; /* Location of the box */
 left: 200px;
 top: 0;
 width: 60%; /* Full width */
 height: 100%; /* Full height */
 overflow: hidden; /* Enable scroll if needed */
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); /* Black w/ opacity */
 }

 /* Modal Content (Image) */
.imagearea {
 display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
float: left;
margin-right:50px;
margin-left: 100px;
max-width: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
```

the following image is the expected output:
[image]

Can someone help me resolve this problem. Thank you

Comment: are you using bootstrap modal ?

Comment: @ash No , i m not using boostrap modal

Comment: if your not using bootstrap modal, are you using any other css library ? or you designed your modal by your own?

Comment: @ash im using jquery-3.2.1.js

Comment: I know your using jquery but how did you designed your modal.. do you have any css for modal? you mean your using jquery ui modal/dialog?

Comment: @ash yes, i have edited my code above

Comment: Don't be `foreach ($gallery as $i)` guy. Be `foreach ($gallery as $imageSource)` guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to show your modal you have to change you javascript code

```
$(function(){
let modal = $('#myModal')     
$(".modal_img").on("click",function(){
     var src = $(this).attr("src");
     modal.css({"display": "block"});
     $("#img01", modal).prop("src",src);
     console.log(src);
    })
   });
```